# Why am I getting this sql syntax error from a Django query?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

In Django I have the following queries in a view

```
applicant=Applicants.objects.get(ben=entity_number)
f471s=applicant.form471_set.order_by("-funding_year","number")
enrollment=f471s.values("schooldata__ben").annotate(f=Max("number")).filter(
           number=F("f")).values().aggregate(
           s=Sum("schooldata__student_count"))['s']
```

When I try to access the page for that view, I get the error

```
DatabaseError
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'FROM (SELECT `frontend_form471`.`number` AS `number`,
`frontend_form471`.`form_s' at line 1")
```

I had the logger print out the SQL that Django is generating and I got

```
(0.001) SELECT  FROM (SELECT `frontend_form471`.`number` AS `number`,
`frontend_form471`.`form_status` AS `form_status`, `frontend_form471`.`ben_id`
AS `ben_id`, `frontend_form471`.`funding_year` AS `funding_year`,
MAX(`frontend_form471`.`number`) AS `f` FROM `frontend_form471` LEFT OUTER JOIN
`SchoolData` ON (`frontend_form471`.`number` = `SchoolData`.`f471 Application Number`)
WHERE (`frontend_form471`.`ben_id` = 122871 ) GROUP BY `frontend_form471`.`number`,
`frontend_form471`.`number`, `frontend_form471`.`form_status`,
`frontend_form471`.`ben_id`, `frontend_form471`.`funding_year` HAVING
`frontend_form471`.`number` =  MAX(`frontend_form471`.`number`) ORDER BY
`frontend_form471`.`funding_year` DESC, `frontend_form471`.`number` ASC) 
subquery; args=(u'122871',)
```

For reference, I am using MySQL 5.1.54-1ubuntu4. It looks like the syntax error is in the first line, but I do not understand why Django is generating SQL code with improper syntax. Is there any way I can change something (a setting, possibly) to fix this?

**Edit:** in response to an answer, I also tried running the third line of python code without the second `.values()` call and got exactly the same effect.

Comment: @S.Lott Yes, but with the table/model name it is qualified enough that it should not be a problem.

Comment: "SELECT  FROM (SELECT "

There is nothing after SELECT - that's invalid SQL syntax! Maybe it is a bug because you're calling values() and it doesn't know about the available fields when you trail all this annotate, aggregate and filter stuff! Try running it without values()...

Comment: @benjaoming you should read the docs on annotate.  Values before is how you create a GROUP BY clause.  So no he shouldn't try it without that

Answer (score 0):

I ended up avoiding the problem by replacing my third line of python code with:

```
latest=SchoolData.objects.filter(f471__ben=entity_number).values(
       'ben').annotate(m=Max('f471__number')).order_by().distinct()
enrollment=sum(SchoolData.objects.filter(ben=l['ben']).get(
           f471__number=l['m']).student_count for l in latest)
```

This worked but it was very slow. In the end some extra information about my data allowed me to optimize like this:

```
latestYear=f471s.aggregate(m=Max('funding_year'))['m']
enrollment=SchoolData.objects.filter(f471__ben=entity_number,
           f471__funding_year=latestYear).distinct().aggregate(
           s=Sum('student_count'))['s']
```

which does not do exactly the same thing but solved my particular problem better.

Answer (score 0):

In case other folks are wondering as I was, this is an accepted Django bug:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15624

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the second empty values() clause after the annotate.  You're literally telling django not to include any columns in the select.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values says that if args is empty, `values()` selects all columns. I previously ran the code without the empty values call and go exactly the same result.

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake try simplifying things.  Remove the second aggregate and the filter on your annotate, and see what you get.  Check that that data looks right and then build it back up.

Comment: I tried that and found that if I change the second `values()` to `values("schooldata__student_count")` then the syntax error disappears but the aggregate call returns an empty dictionary. I now realize I can avoid the problem using `values_list` and `sum`.

Comment: @murgatroid: That was point previously, and I think you should debug it further and submit a bug report. Probably values() is not able to resolve field names passed down in your chain of calls.